# How to derive the Hamiltonian of general relativity (ADM formalism without surface terms)?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, constrained-dynamics, adm-formalism

Given that $$ds^{2} =−N^{2}dt^{2} +h_{ij}(dx^{i} +N^{i}dt)(dx^{j}+N^{j}dt)$$

$$S=\int dt d^{3} x\sqrt{h} N(^{3}R+K_{ij}+K^{ij}-K^{2})$$

where $^{3}R$ is the Ricci scalar of $hij$, $h$ the determinant of $hij$ and $K_{ij}= \frac{1}{2N}(∂_{t}h_{ij}−D_{i}N_{j}−D_{j}N_{I})$, and $K=h_{ij}K_{ij}$,

how does one get

$$H=\int{\text{d}^3x\sqrt{h}(N\mathcal{H}+N^i\mathcal{H}_i)}~?$$

Comment: IIRC there's a fairly good treatment of this in Wald's *General Relativity*, Appendix E.